# How to filter with different conditions in different rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Data structure:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~"group", ~"word",
  1,"apple",
  1,"orange",
  1,"apple cider",
  1,"orange juice",
  1,"pear",
  1,"pear",
  2,"apple",
  2,"pear",
  3,"orange juice",
  3,"apple",
  4,"pear",
  4,"guava"
  )
```

I would like to filter with str_detect of the words "apple" AND "orange" on column "word". Return only observations if the "group" contains both words "apple" and "orange".

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  group word        
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 apple       
2     1 orange      
3     1 apple cider 
4     1 orange juice
5     3 orange juice
6     3 apple
```

Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can filter those groups which have at least one value of `"apple"` as well as `"orange"` and only those rows in that group which has either `"apple"` or `"orange"` in `word`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(any(str_detect(word, 'apple')) & any(str_detect(word, 'orange')) & 
            str_detect(word, 'orange|apple'))

# group word        
#  <dbl> <chr>       
#1     1 apple       
#2     1 orange      
#3     1 apple cider 
#4     1 orange juice     
#7     3 orange juice
#8     3 apple
```

Comment: thanks. Can you explain the math behind any(str_detect(word, 'apple')) & any(str_detect(word, 'orange')) & str_detect(word, 'orange|apple')? I have a difficult time understanding it

Comment: `any(str_detect(word, 'apple')) & any(str_detect(word, 'orange'))` selects only those groups that have both 'apple' and 'orange'. Additional `str_detect(word, 'orange|apple')` is to select those rows that have only 'orange' and 'apple' within those groups.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(word, 'apple|orange'))
```

Comment: this filters group 2 too, different ouput

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_extract` and `n_distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    filter((n_distinct(unlist(str_extract_all(word, "apple|orange"))) >1) &
          str_detect(word, 'apple|orange'))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group word        
#  <dbl> <chr>       
#1     1 apple       
#2     1 orange      
#3     1 apple cider 
#4     1 orange juice
#5     3 orange juice
#6     3 apple
```

---

**Explanation**

After grouping by 'group', we extract all the 'word' that are either 'apple' or 'orange' with `str_extract_all` (the output will be a `list` by default), `unlist` the `list`, and count the number of distinct elements (`n_distinct`), check if it is greater than 1 as one condition which is joined with another condition that checks whether the 'word' column includes 'apple' or 'orange' (`str_detect`).  Basically, it will only get those groups having both the cases and remove any other element in the process as well i.e. if we use only the first expression

```
df %>% 
     group_by(group) %>% 
     filter((n_distinct(unlist(str_extract_all(word, "apple|orange"))) >1))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group word        
#  <dbl> <chr>       
#1     1 apple       
#2     1 orange      
#3     1 apple cider 
#4     1 orange juice
#5     1 pear      # // not needed, but it was kept 
#6     1 pear      # // because it is checking on distinct element  
#7     3 orange juice
#8     3 apple
```

With second expression alone

```
df %>% 
     group_by(group) %>% filter(str_detect(word, 'apple|orange'))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   group [3]
#  group word        
#  <dbl> <chr>       
#1     1 apple       
#2     1 orange      
#3     1 apple cider 
#4     1 orange juice
#5     2 apple    # // also keeps group 2 that includes only apple    
#6     3 orange juice
#7     3 apple
```

By doing the `&`, the group 2 will be removed as well as the elements such as 'pear' in 'word' column

Comment: interesting, this looks much more elegant. Do you mind explaining the meaning behind the code? thanks

Comment: @KKW Can you check now.  Hope it is more clear.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df,
  as.logical(
    ave(
      word,
      group,
      FUN = function(x) any(grepl("apple", x)) & any(grepl("orange", x)) & grepl("apple|orange", x)
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  group word
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 apple
2     1 orange
3     1 apple cider
4     1 orange juice
5     3 orange juice
6     3 apple
```